# Image on top of a Div with Background image set

Tags: html, background-image

I'm having a small problem, that I just cannot figure out.

I have a div with a background image set:

```
#menu {height: 44px; background:url(../images/menuback.jpg) repeat-x; position: relative;}
```

I have an image and I want it to appear on top of the div, but it keeps going behind it, css as follows:

```
.logoImage {position:absolute; margin-top:40px;}
```

HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="grid_16" id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="~~home~~"><img class="logoImage" src="~~themeDir~~images/logo.jpg" alt="~~siteTitle~~"/></a>
                <a href="~~home~~"><img class="logoWriting" src="~~themeDir~~images/logo_writing.jpg" alt="~~siteTitle~~"/></a>            
            </div>
            <div class="searchbox">
                <form action="~~home~~searchmachine" method="post" id="searchform">
                    <h3>
                        Search: 
                        <input type="text" value="" name="search" />
                        <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="$('#searchform').submit()" class="searchbutton">Go</a> 
                    </h3>                                       
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="grid_16" id="menu">
            <ul class="dropmenu">
                <li><a href="~~home~~">Home</a></li>
                ~~startCatsMenu~~
                    <li><a href="~~catLink~~">~~catTitle~~</a>
                        ~~startSubCats~~
                            <ul>
                                ~~startSubCat~~
                                <li><a href="~~subCatLink~~">~~subCatTitle~~</a></li>
                                ~~endSubCat~~
                            </ul>
                        ~~endSubCats~~
                    </li>
                ~~endCatsMenu~~
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
```

regards,
Stephen

Comment: Why do you have the position of .logoImage as absolute? Is there another class it's a part of that moves it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I place everything within one div, then I managed to move the images are required.